# radio button php POST

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, mail-form

I am trying to create a feedback form for my website that has radio buttons for people to rank their experience.

I have looked at various options on Stack Overflow to help, but I cannot find anything that works. The basic fiels like name etc work as I have used them on other forms. I just cannot get the radio buttons to submit information.

When I fill the form and click submit, nothing happens, but my URL changes to www.whateversite.com?xxx_the_options_selected_on_the_form

Any help as to where I have gone wrong or how to fix it would be appreciated.

This is my current HTML - I tried to clean it up as much as possible and present it neatly.

```
<form id="feedback-form" name="feedback-form" role="form">
            <p>Please rate the following - with 5 being the
            best</p><label for="exp">Overall Experience:</label>
            <div class="radio">
                    <label class="radio-inline" for="exp1">
                    <input id="exp1" name="exp" type="radio" value="option1">1
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline" for="exp2">
                    <input id="exp2" name="exp" type="radio" value="option2">2
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline" for="exp3">
                    <input id="exp3" name="exp" type="radio" value="option3">3
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline" for="exp4">
                    <input id="exp4" name="exp" type="radio" value="option4">4
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline" for="exp5">
                    <input id="exp5" name="exp" type="radio" value="option5">5
                    </label>
            </div><label for="staf">Friendliness of Staff:</label>
            <div class="radio">
                    <label class="radio-inline" for="staf1"><input id=
                    "staf1" name="staf" type="radio" value=
                    "option1">1</label> <label class="radio-inline" for=
                    "staf2"><input id="staf2" name="staf" type="radio"
                    value="option2">2</label> <label class="radio-inline"
                    for="staf3"><input id="staf3" name="staf" type="radio"
                    value="option3">3</label> <label class="radio-inline"
                    for="staf4"><input id="staf4" name="staf" type="radio"
                    value="option4">4</label> <label class="radio-inline"
                    for="staf5"><input id="staf5" name="staf" type="radio"
                    value="option5">5</label>
            </div><label for="clean">Cleanliness of facility:</label>
            <div class="radio">
                    <label class="radio-inline" for="clean1"><input id=
                    "clean1" name="clean" type="radio" value=
                    "option1">1</label> <label class="radio-inline" for=
                    "clean2"><input id="clean2" name="clean" type="radio"
                    value="option2">2</label> <label class="radio-inline"
                    for="clean3"><input id="clean3" name="clean" type=
                    "radio" value="option3">3</label> <label class=
                    "radio-inline" for="clean4"><input id="clean4" name=
                    "clean" type="radio" value="option4">4</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline" for="clean5"><input id=
                    "clean5" name="clean" type="radio" value=
                    "option5">5</label>
            </div><label for="refer">Would you refer a friend?</label>
            <div class="radio">
                    <label class="radio-inline" for="refer1"><input id=
                    "refer1" name="refer" type="radio" value=
                    "option1">1</label> <label class="radio-inline" for=
                    "refer2"><input id="refer2" name="refer" type="radio"
                    value="option2">2</label> <label class="radio-inline"
                    for="refer3"><input id="refer3" name="refer" type=
                    "radio" value="option3">3</label> <label class=
                    "radio-inline" for="refer4"><input id="refer4" name=
                    "refer" type="radio" value="option4">4</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline" for="refer5"><input id=
                    "refer4" name="refer" type="radio" value=
                    "option5">5</label>
            </div><br>
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <p>If you would like our manager to contact you please
                    provide the following information:</p><label for=
                    "name">Full Name*</label> <input class="form-control"
                    id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Full Name"
                    type="text"> <i class=
                    "fa fa-user form-control-feedback"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <label for="email">Email*</label> <input class=
                    "form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder=
                    "e.g. someone@mail.com" type="email"> <i class=
                    "fa fa-envelope form-control-feedback"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <label for="phone">Contact Number*</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone"
                    placeholder="0400000000" type="phone"> <i class=
                    "fa fa-phone form-control-feedback"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="subject">Please share your thoughts on how
                    we may improve your experience</label> <input class=
                    "form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder=
                    "Please leave your thoughts here..." type="text">
                    <i class="fa fa-navicon form-control-feedback"></i>
            </div><input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value=
            "Submit">
    </form>
```

My Current PHP is

```
<?php
session_cache_limiter('nocache');
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('r', 0));

header('Content-type: application/json');

// Enter your email address below.
$to = 'smile@smilehawthorn.com.au';

$subject = 'Website Feedback Received';

if($to) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $fields = array(
                    0 => array(
                        'text' => 'Name',
                        'val' => $_POST['name']),
                    1 => array(
                        'text' => 'Email address',
                        'val' => $_POST['email']),
                    2 => array(
                        'text' => 'Contact Number',
                        'val' => $_POST['phone']),
                    3 => array(
                        $exp => $_POST['exp']),
                    4 => array(
                        $staf => $_POST['staf']),
                    5 => array(
                        $clean => $_POST['clean']),
                    6 => array(
                        $refer => $_POST['refer']),
                    7 => array(
                        'text' => 'Subject',
                        'val' => $_POST['subject'])
                );

    $message = "";

    foreach($fields as $field) {
        $message .= $field['text'].": " . htmlspecialchars($field['val'], ENT_QUOTES) . "<br>\n";
    }

    $headers = '';
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $name . ' <' . $email . '>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: " .  $email . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
        $arrResult = array ('response'=>'success');
    } else{
        $arrResult = array ('response'=>'error');
    }

    echo json_encode($arrResult);

} else {

    $arrResult = array ('response'=>'error');
    echo json_encode($arrResult);
}
?>
```

And finally the JS that checks the feedback for required fields

```
// feedback forms validation
    //-----------------------------------------------       
    if($("#feedback-form").length>0) {
        $("#feedback-form").validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {

                var submitButton = $(this.submitButton);
                submitButton.button("loading");

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "php/feedback-form.php",
                    data: {
                        "name": $("#feedback-form #name").val(),
                        "phone": $("#feedback-form #phone").val(),
                        "email": $("#feedback-form #email").val(),
                        "exp": $("#feedback-form #exp").val(),
                        "staf": $("#feedback-form #staf").val(),
                        "clean": $("#feedback-form #clean").val(),
                        "refer": $("#feedback-form #refer").val(),
                        "subject": $("#feedback-form #subject").val()
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.response == "success") {

                            $("#contactSuccess").removeClass("hidden");
                            $("#contactError").addClass("hidden");

                            // Reset Form
                            $("#feedback-form .form-control")
                                .val("")
                                .blur()
                                .parent()
                                .removeClass("has-success")
                                .removeClass("has-error")
                                .find("label")
                                .removeClass("hide")
                                .parent()
                                .find("span.error")
                                .remove();

                            if(($("#contactSuccess").position().top - 80) < $(window).scrollTop()){
                                $("html, body").animate({
                                     scrollTop: $("#contactSuccess").offset().top - 80
                                }, 300);
                            }

                        } else {

                            $("#contactError").removeClass("hidden");
                            $("#contactSuccess").addClass("hidden");

                            if(($("#contactError").position().top - 80) < $(window).scrollTop()){
                                $("html, body").animate({
                                     scrollTop: $("#contactError").offset().top - 80
                                }, 300);
                            }

                        }
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        submitButton.button("reset");
                    }
                });
            },              
            // debug: true,
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.insertBefore( element );
            },
            onkeyup: false,
            onclick: false,
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                phone: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 10
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                name: {
                    required: "Please specify your name",
                    minlength: "Your name must be longer than 2 characters"
                },
                phone: {
                    required: "We need your phone number to contact you if required",
                    email: "Please enter a valid contact number 0401001002 or 0390909090"
                },
                email: {
                    required: "We need your email address to contact you",
                    email: "Please enter a valid email address e.g. name@domain.com"
                }               
            },
            errorElement: "span",
            highlight: function (element) {
                $(element).parent().removeClass("has-success").addClass("has-error");
                $(element).siblings("label").addClass("hide"); 
            },
            success: function (element) {
                $(element).parent().removeClass("has-error").addClass("has-success");
                $(element).siblings("label").removeClass("hide"); 
            }
        });
    };      
    //end feedback form
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: form method is post? I dont see it..

Comment: A HTML Form has a "method" attribute, which will specify the type of HTTP request that happens when you submit, by default, it is a `GET` request, which is why you see all the values appended to the URL.  I think you want to set: `method="POST"`: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.1

Comment: @ymas Actually I think he is submitting the form using an AJAX call that is using `POST`

Comment: See @DaTebe answer. I think that will solve your problem

Comment: I don't think all that code is needed to demonstrate your problem. Please provide a *minimal* example.

Comment: Thank you @RiggsFolly, I believe the OP is using the JQuery Validate plugin and needs to review his submitHandler as per: https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuerys ajax function to send the form and not the native form-tag use this to get the selected radio button (example for refer):

```
$("input[name='refer']:checked").val()
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked beautifully. With your advice I managed to add a checkbox as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am guessing you want a row of options with values ranging from, lets say 1 - 5 where 1 is a horrible experience and 5 is amazing, I'd probably do that like this:

HTML:

```
<form action="page-goes-here" method="POST">
  <p>
  Please rate your experience (1 = horrible, 5 = amazing)
  </p>
  <ul class="myList">
   <li>1</li>
   <li><input type="radio" name="userExperience" value="1" /></li>
   <li><input type="radio" name="userExperience" value="2" /></li>
   <li><input type="radio" name="userExperience" value="3" /></li>
   <li><input type="radio" name="userExperience" value="4" /></li>
   <li><input type="radio" name="userExperience" value="5" /></li>
   <li>5</li>
  </ul>
  <input type="submit" name="submitExperience" value="Submit" />
 </form>
 <hr />
```

CSS:

```
.myList li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-table;
}
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST["submitExperience"])) {

   $userExperience = $_POST["userExperience"]; // This variable should now contain a value between 1-5, depending on what the user chose

}
```